# Javascript: Eventhandlers properties

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function which passes two arguments: function(target, event)
like this:

```
    function doSo(e) {
    alert(e.clientX + " " + this.className);
};

main.onclick = doSo;
```

it works just fine, 
but when I want to specify the target, like:

```
function doSo(elt, e) {
    alert(e.clientX + " " + elt.className);
};

main.onclick = doSo(this,e);
```

The debugger always returns "e is not defined".

I thought e as a property "embedded" within the eventhandlers.

Or, how can I pass those two arguments to the function??
I need to do so for a drag function which specifies the element to drag AND the event, but I always get event as undefined.

Has it to do with the order of the arguments?

Comment: You want `this` to be your `main` element ?

Comment: try to use event.target

Comment: What you want? Access on element or pass params to function?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="id_" class="class_">click</div>
<script>
    function get_data(e) { alert(e.clientX + '|' + e.target.className) }
    document.getElementById('id_').onclick = function (e) { get_data(e) }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Event in JS by-default have only one parameter that's why **e** is **undefined**.

```
function doSo(elt, e) {
    alert(e.clientX + " " + elt.className);
};
```

here **elt** is the event returned by JS, **elt.clientX** will work but not **e.clentX**.

**How to pass those two arguments to the function?**

Natively you can't, but there must be something like this within the library you are using for Drag n Drop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your function such that it can take the params, then proxy calls to it:

```
function doSo (elt, e) {
    alert(e.clientX + " " + elt.className);
};

function doSo_ClickProxy (e) {
    doSo(this, e);
}

main.onclick = doSo_ClickProxy;
```

The basic concept behind this is what drives how event libraries (like jQuery, for example) provide the functionality they do (although they proxy it such that the event is passed first, then other arguments if desired).

Answer (score 0):

```
    function doSo(elt, e) {
        alert(e.clientX + " " + elt.className);
    };
    main.onclick = function (e) { doSo(this, e); };
```